# Finding the coordinate vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ ,$U= \text{span} \{v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2\}$ and $B= \{v_1+2v_2,v_2\}$. Prove that $B$ is a basis in $U$ and find coordinate vector of  $v_1$ with respect to $B$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step: show that $v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2$ are  linearly dependent . Cnclusion: $ \dim U=2.$

Second step: show that $B \subseteq U.$

Third step: show that $v_1+2v_2, v_2$ are  linearly independent.

These steps give:  $\text{span}B=U$, hence $B$ is a basis of $U$.

For the rest make the "Ansatz": $v_1=a(v_1+2v_2)+bv_2$ for $a,b \in \mathbb R.$ Compute $a $ and $b.$

Comment: I still don't know how to find a and b

Comment: $v_1=a(v_1+2v_2)+bv_2 \iff (a-1)v_1+(2a+b)v_2=0.$ Now use that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you ! But why are $v_1$+2 $v_2$ and $v_2$ linearly independent?

Comment: "Ansatz": $0= \alpha (v_1+2v_2)+\beta v_2=0$ Use that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent and show $ \alpha= \beta=0.$

Comment: But, if $\alpha= \beta$=0 then the vectors $v_1$ ,$v_2$ , $v_1$+$v_2$ shouldn't be linearly independent ?